# Akka Streams: KillSwitch for custom SourceShape emitting frames from video file

Tags: scala, opencv, akka, akka-stream

Following the [documentation to implement a `KillSwitch`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stream-dynamic.html#Controlling_graph_completion_with_KillSwitch), I was able to code this simple example for stopping a Source emitting infinite numbers.

```
object KillSwitchSample extends App {
  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val sourceGraph: Graph[SourceShape[Int], NotUsed] = new NumbersSource
  val mySource: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source.fromGraph(sourceGraph)

  val killSwitch = KillSwitches.shared("switch")

  RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._
    val flow = builder.add(Flow[Int].map(_ * 2))
    mySource.via(killSwitch.flow) ~> flow ~> Sink.foreach(println)
    ClosedShape
  }).run()

  Thread.sleep(200)

  killSwitch.shutdown()
}

class NumbersSource extends GraphStage[SourceShape[Int]] {
  val out: Outlet[Int] = Outlet("NumbersSource")
  override val shape: SourceShape[Int] = SourceShape(out)

  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic =
    new GraphStageLogic(shape) {
      private var counter = 1

      setHandler(out, new OutHandler {
        override def onPull(): Unit = {
          push(out, counter)
          counter += 1
        }
      })
    }
}
```

My use case is different in the sense that the Source emits frames from a video file using OpenCV. Why is the upstream not cancelled? What am I missing here?

```
object KillSwitchMinimalMain extends App {
  val libopencv_java = new File("lib").listFiles().map(_.getAbsolutePath).filter(_.contains("libopencv_java"))
  System.load(libopencv_java(0))

  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val videoFile = Video("Video.MOV")

  val sourceGraph: Graph[SourceShape[Frame], NotUsed] = new VideoSource(videoFile)
  val videoSource: Source[Frame, NotUsed] = Source.fromGraph(sourceGraph)

  val killSwitch = KillSwitches.shared("switch")

  RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    val matConversion: FlowShape[Frame, Image] = builder.add(Flow[Frame].map { el => MediaConversion.convertMatToImage(el.frame) })

    videoSource.via(killSwitch.flow) ~> matConversion ~> Sink.foreach(println)

    ClosedShape
  }).run()

  Thread.sleep(200)

  killSwitch.shutdown()
}

class VideoSource(videoFile: Video) extends GraphStage[SourceShape[Frame]] {
  val out: Outlet[Frame] = Outlet("VideoSource")
  override val shape: SourceShape[Frame] = SourceShape(out)
  val log: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)

  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic =
    new GraphStageLogic(shape) {
      private val capture = new VideoCapture()
      private val frame = new Mat()
      private var videoPos: Double = _

      override def preStart(): Unit = {
        capture.open(videoFile.filepath)
        readFrame()
      }

      setHandler(out, new OutHandler {
        override def onPull(): Unit = {
          push(out, Frame(videoPos, frame))
          readFrame()
        }
      })

      private def readFrame(): Unit = {
        if (capture.isOpened) {
          videoPos = capture.get(1)
          log.info(s"reading frame $videoPos")
          capture.read(frame)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

The console output as asked by @svezfaz:

```
13:17:00.046 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO de.itd.video.VideoSource - reading frame 0.0
13:17:00.160 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO de.itd.video.VideoSource - reading frame 1.0
javafx.scene.image.WritableImage@64b06f30
13:17:00.698 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO de.itd.video.VideoSource - reading frame 2.0
javafx.scene.image.WritableImage@1e011979
13:17:00.826 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO de.itd.video.VideoSource - reading frame 3.0
javafx.scene.image.WritableImage@52c9a35c
13:17:00.969 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO de.itd.video.VideoSource - reading frame 4.0
javafx.scene.image.WritableImage@13968f9e
13:17:01.137 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO de.itd.video.VideoSource - reading frame 5.0
javafx.scene.image.WritableImage@6ab783be
// and so on ..
```

Comment: Could you detail what output do you see when you run the OpenCV example? Do you know how long does one frame pull take?

Comment: I updated the question with a logger showing that frames are read quite fast (still much slower than emitting Integers of course). `javafx.scene.image.WritableImage@xxxxxxxx` is the `println` of the Sink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you introduce blocking in your custom stage. I don't know the OpenCV API, but I'm guessing it happens when you call `capture.read(frame)`.
Now, unless otherwise instructed, your graph will be run in one single Actor, therefore blocking in your stage will block the whole actor.

Forcing an `async` boundary after your source should do the trick.

Also note that you don't need a GraphDSL here, everything can be run compactly using the via/to DSL.

Solution attempt below

```
object KillSwitchMinimalMain extends App {
  val libopencv_java = new File("lib").listFiles().map(_.getAbsolutePath).filter(_.contains("libopencv_java"))

  System.load(libopencv_java(0))
  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val videoFile = Video("Video.MOV")

  val killSwitch = KillSwitches.shared("switch")
  val matConversion = Flow[ByteString].map { _.utf8String }

  Source.fromGraph(new VideoSource())
    .async
    .via(killSwitch.flow)
    .via(matConversion)
    .runForeach(println)

  Thread.sleep(200)

  killSwitch.shutdown()
}
```

For more info on the concurrency model underlying Akka Streams you can read this [blogpost](http://blog.akka.io/streams/2016/07/06/threading-and-concurrency-in-akka-streams-explained).

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. I remember reading about this in the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#Operator_Fusion) but obviously couldn't really apply it. 
Regarding the GraphDSL, I'm aware that it is not necessary here but the posted code is a boiled down version omitting my broadcast and merge stages. But since you mentioned it: Is there any other downside using GraphDSL besides that it is more verbose?

Comment: Another downside worth mentioning is that the GraphDSL is slightly more fragile and prone to runtime errors, wherever inlets and outlets are not all properly connected. No big differences performance-wise that I'm aware of.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.